# Intuition behind why NP could be equals to co-NP , if we "assume" P not equals NP

Tags: computer-science, complexity-theory, np

if we "assume" P not equals NP , [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9795/is-the-open-question-np-co-np-the-same-as-p-np) and [this](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec6.html) suggests NP could be equals to co-NP .

I searched a lot , and went through a lot of materials . I can't seem to quite intuitively understand why this could be true . It would be really helpful if someone can lead me to any resource or help me intuitively understand why this could be true .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question. It is a question about the theory of computing. try cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible intuition, which could be totally misguided given that we haven't yet resolved **P** versus **NP**.

The complexity class **P** can be thought of as all problems for which the following statement is true: there's a boolean function `solveProblem` such that

- `solveProblem` runs in polynomial time in the size of its input,
- for any input `x` where the answer is "yes," `solveProblem(x)` returns true, and
- for any input `x` where the answer is "no," `solveProblem(x)` returns false.

Now, let's look at the definition of **NP**. It's the set of problems for which the following statement is true: there's a boolean function `checkYesAnswer` such that

- `checkYesAnswer` runs in polynomial time,
- for any input `x` where the answer is "yes", there is some `y` where `checkYesAnswer(x, y)` returns true, and
- for any input `x` where the answer is "no," `checkYesAnswer(x, y)` always returns false.

The difference between **P** and **NP**, then, is that when you're looking at the complexity class **P**, you're given just the input and need to make a yes/no determination, whereas in the class **NP** there may be some auxiliary information that helps you make a yes/no decision. That makes the distinction between the definitions of **P** and **NP** pretty large - in one case you need to solve the problem, and in the other you need to check whether some auxiliary information helps you.

Now, here's another, equivalent definition of co-**NP**. The class co-**NP** consists of all problems where there's a boolean function `checkNoAnswer` such that

- `checkNoAnswer` runs in polynomial time,
- for any input `x` where the answer is "yes," `checkNoAnswer(x, y)` always returns true, and
- for any input `x` where the answer is "no," there is a choice of `y` where `checkNoAnswer(x, y)` returns true.

In other words, the definitions of **NP** and co-**NP** are very closely related to one another, with the only difference being that the branches for "yes" and "no" are swapped. So in that sense, even if **P** ≠ **NP**, it still could be plausible that **NP** and co-**NP** could be equal, since we're basically just flipping the role of the words "yes" and "no."

There's also good reasons to see why **NP** might not be co-**NP**. You can think of the distinction between the definitions as follows: with **NP**, the answer is "yes" if *there exists* some `y` with some property, whereas with co-**NP** the answer is "yes" if *for all* `y` something holds. And since the ∃ and ∀ quantifiers work differently, perhaps there's something else going on here.

Answer (score -1):

If P=NP, then NP=co-NP. The proof for this statement critically depends on the assumption P=NP.

Now if P!=NP, the proof does not work, and so the question whether NP=co-NP remains open. It's as simple as that.